# Proving that $\left|\Re\left( \frac{1+i\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)^n\right| \to \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

> Let $u_n=\displaystyle\Re\left( \frac{1+i\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)^n$
>
> Prove that $|u_n| \to \infty$

This appeared in a recent issue of French *Revue de la Filière Mathématiques*, as it was reportedly asked during an oral exam.

The editor deems it is an "extremely difficult problem", and uses Skolem–Mahler–Lech theorem to prove the result.

They're also looking for a proof an undergraduate could find.

Do you know one ?

Comment: It amounts to showing $$2^{n/2}\cos(n\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{7})) \to\infty $$ ...which does appear very difficult.

Comment: It might help to write the recurrence: $$u_{n+1} = u_n - 2u_{n-1},u_0=1, u_1=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: I tried proving this with SML by myself. Even with SML, it is difficult.

Comment: I flag it to duplicate because Noam Elkies's proof is 'elementary' but I wouldn't say that it can be done by an undergraduate..